# NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, arraylist, nullpointerexception

So I have this code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.favourites);
    assert getSupportActionBar() != null;
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("myFavs", 0);
    Map<String, String> m = (Map<String, String>) prefs.getAll();
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(m.values());

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.favsList);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,R.layout.listlayout, android.R.id.text1, list );
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And it outputs this error in logcat:

```
10-08 08:48:44.114  19390-19390/com.example.me1jmo.insult_generator E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.me1jmo.insult_generator, PID: 19390
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:399)
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:369)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2346)
        at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1280)
        at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1188)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
        ...
```

I have read the articles on why this happens but I can't figure out what bit of my code I need to change to get it working.

Comment: can you post "listlayout" code. Use textview in listlayout rather than standard android.R.id.text1

Comment: Can you share your listlayout

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is coming because you are referring the Textview which is not in your specified layout.

```
android.R.id.text1
```

is a Textview of Android OS classes which is inbuilt in OS.

You need to use the id of the Textview which you have specified in the

```
R.layout.listlayout
```

Change that and your error will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `android.R.id.text1` to `R.id.text1`. Also, check if your `listlayout` has a TextView with id `text1`.

Answer (score 0):

**Replace this**

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,R.layout.listlayout, android.R.id.text1, list );
```

**With this**

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, list );
```